# How to find out focal length of camera in ios and what is the sensor height?

Tags: ios

I had searched every where for finding focal length of the camera and its back sensor height.
But I didn't get any specific detail.

I am developing one app which will calculate the actual height of an real world object from the height visible in the image captured from an ios camera.

distance to object (mm) =

focal length (mm) * real height of the object (mm) * image height (pixels)  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
             object height (pixels) * sensor height (mm)

here I am having the values distance to object as static, image height in pixel. Now I need focal length and sensor height to find out the real object height.

Thanks in advance.
bskania

Comment: it is a very interesting question! Did you have any progress since then?

Comment: no i didn't find any solution for this.But I had changed the way to find out the object distance.

Comment: Could you share you answer here? By the way you could form it as a self-accepted answer to this question.

Comment: +1, Have you found any solution ?

Comment: Yes, I had posted it below as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to solve this issue.

First take one real world object and its measure i.e. height and width.(example of coke cane)
Now take a snap of the object that you want to measure.
For the iphone or ipad the focal length is fixed to 25mm.
Now frame the object that you want to measure on a snap and re-size the real world coke cane image according to the object you want to measure.

use the equation

object_distance = (focal * real_object_height)/object_height;

here, real_object_height = coke cane height;
and object_height = coke cane re-sized height

and accordingly measure the height of object using equation

height_of_frame = ((obj_distance) * measured_object_height_in_mm / 1000.0))/focal;

width_of_frame = ((obj_distance) * measured_object_width_in_mm / 1000.0))/focal;

this way you can find out the object distance and its measure.
but you need two static data i.e. focal length of camera which you are using and the one real world object measure to compare.

thanks,
bskania.

Comment: can we measure hight and width of any object in image ? where we nothing found like distance etc

Comment: yes we can find. but for that lense focal and one relative object height and width should be as known factor. working application on this formula https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/fishweight/id785343148?mt=8

Comment: @BSKANIA real_object_height and object_height pass into which format like pixel, cm or inches. And What is measured_object_height_in_mm?

Comment: @BSKANIA is this reproducible for different type of devices? or is it for a particular set of devices? In my opinion it won't work with different devices like Android phone, Android tablets, iphone and ipad. What is your opinion?

Answer (score 5):

#### EXIF Headers

iOS devices provide the camera's focal-length value in the JPEG EXIF headers. It is visible within `iPhoto` and just about any other tool.

#### Options for retrieving it programmatically

- [Apple Technical Q&A QA1622](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1622/_index.html) discusses ALAssetsLibrary
- [Accessing Image Properties](http://oleb.net/blog/2011/09/accessing-image-properties-without-loading-the-image-into-memory/) uses CGImageSourceRef

The list of EXIF header keys can be found in the [CGImageProperties Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGImageProperties_Reference/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/EXIF_Dictionary_Keys).

```
NSURL *imageFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:...];
CGImageSourceRef imageSource = CGImageSourceCreateWithURL((CFURLRef)imageFileURL, NULL);
if (imageSource == NULL) {
    // Error loading image
    ...
    return;
}

NSDictionary *options = @{kCGImageSourceShouldCache, @NO};
CFDictionaryRef imageProperties = CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex(imageSource, 0, (CFDictionaryRef)options);
if (imageProperties) {
    NSNumber *width = (NSNumber *)CFDictionaryGetValue(imageProperties, kCGImagePropertyPixelWidth);
    NSNumber *height = (NSNumber *)CFDictionaryGetValue(imageProperties, kCGImagePropertyPixelHeight);
    NSLog(@"Image dimensions: %@ x %@ px", width, height);
    CFRelease(imageProperties);
}
CFRelease(imageSource);
```

Comment: CGImageSourceRef is certainly one place to get a dictionary of meta-data from the image. CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex is the specific function call.