# How to assign image size based on distance

Tags: ios, objective-c, image-processing, augmented-reality, core-motion

I'm assigning the image size based on the predefined (for example) distance and image width & height. I referred these links: [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11913355/scaling-ar-pictures-based-on-the-distance-from-the-camera) [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13190932/how-to-find-out-focal-length-of-camera-in-ios-and-what-is-the-sensor-height?lq=1)

```
height_of_frame = ((obj_distance) * measured_object_height_in_mm / 1000.0))/focal;

width_of_frame = ((obj_distance) * measured_object_width_in_mm / 1000.0))/focal;

int imagesize_height = ((152.4)*1990/1000)/0.33;

int imagesize_width = ((152.4)*3500/1000)/0.33;
```

distance in cm = 152.4 and ipadMini camera focal length is 3.3mm = 0.33cm

But, if i do this it reducing the image size not close or near.

Imagesize based on aspect ratio:

```
CGFloat widthRatio = self.view.frame.size.width / enteredRoomSize.width;
 CGFloat heightRatio = self.view.frame.size.height / enteredRoomSize.height;

  CGSize imageSize = CGSizeMake(350 * widthRatio, 199 * widthRatio);

 mmageView=[[UIImageView alloc]init];

 CGRect frame = mmageView.frame; frame.size = imageSize; mmageView.frame = frame;
```

Comment: I edited my answer to match your notations, but you need to clarify your question... What do you mean by "But, if i do this it reducing the image size not close or near." ?

Answer (score 0):

This is basic mathematics. The formula is:

```
object_distance = (focal * real_object_height)/object_height;
```

Hence you should have:

```
height_of_frame = (focal * measured_object_height_in_mm / 1000.0))/obj_distance;

width_of_frame = (focal  * measured_object_width_in_mm / 1000.0))/obj_distance;
```

Also, `height_of_frame` will have the same unit as `focal` (usually pixels) and `obj_distance` should be in meters, not in centimeters.

Comment: What is real_object_height. I'm overlaying images on the camera view for augmented Reality application. The images just overlaying on the camera view, it isn't in-front of cameraview

Comment: I have image on the camera overlay not in-front of the camera view. So, do i need to use measured_object_height_in_mm in the overlay image? Then based on the distance and focal length i need to overlay the image with height & width